# ANTLRv4: Parsing comments until end-of-line

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer

I'm using ANTLRv4 to parse a simple structured file like this one:

```
; Comment (works)
    ; This comment is also ok.
;
; The previous line is not tokenized :(
end ; Comment on some instruction (works)
```

When using this source file with the generated parser, I always get an error with line 3:

```
line 3:1 token recognition error at: '\n'
```

I could track down the error in the generated lexer.

I'm using this lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar SimpleLexer;

WS              : [ \t] -> skip;
EOL             : [\r\n];
END             : [eE][nN][dD] ;
SEMICOLON       : ';' -> mode(COMMENT_MODE);
IDENTIFIER      : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')* ;

fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;

mode COMMENT_MODE;
COMMENT_TEXT    : (~'\n')* -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

(Note: It's important to get the comment text, too. It may contain some meta-information.)

Does anyone have suggestions to get this lexer working with empty comments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try (~[\n])*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mode COMMENT_MODE;
COMMENT_TEXT: (~('\n' | EOF))*;
END: '\n' | EOF -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

The EOF addition ensures parsing also succeeds if there is no trailing linebreak after the last line.

Comment: I had to change the last line to "END: ('\n' | EOL) -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);", but this is it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah right, otherwise ANTLR interprets that as action on a single alt. Didn't think of that. OK, if my answer helped you then please accept it (the check mark below the vote count).